# React Native overlapping touchables trigger at the same time

Tags: react-native

I've got two Touchables that overlap. Clicking the overlapping area makes them both fire. I want only the child onPress event to trigger (i.e. only the onUpVote/onDownVote function).

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={onPress} underlayColor={colors.focus}>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <AppText>{question.content}</AppText>
    <View style={styles.voteContainer}>
      <UpVoteButton
        voted={voted}
        voteCount={question.upVotes}
        onPress={onUpVote}
      />
      <DownVoteButton
        voted={false}
        voteCount={question.downVotes}
        onPress={onDownVote}
      />
    </View>
  </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

and that's the VoteButton element

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPress}>
  <View style={styles.voteContainer}>
    <AppText style={styles.voteCount}>{voteCount}</AppText>
    <AntDesign
      name={voted ? "like1" : "like2"}
      style={{
        fontSize: 18,
        color: defaultStyles.colors.focus,
        paddingBottom: 3,
      }}
    />
  </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

The idea is that if the user presses the thumbs up/down icon area then the onDownVote gets handled. Pressing anywhere else within the list item is supposed to take you to a different screen.

[App layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIJqV.png)

Comment: Is there a specific reason for you to have them overlap each other ? If not Why not get rid of the overlap ? Asking because don't see your design, need to have an idea.

Comment: I added the app layout and logic behind it to the description.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to import `TouchableOpacity` from here:
https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler

Both overlapping touchables should fire `onPress` prop